# How do I show the certificate thumbnail for a newly created certificate using certreq in powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssl, certreq

I am using the following command in PowerShell which works fine and good:

```
certreq -accept -machine "c:\my_csr_response.crt"
```

This command processes a CA response to a SSL CSR.

My question is how do I get the thumbnail of the newly created certificate generated by this command?

Comment: Try this `Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\ -Recurse | Where NotBefore -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` This assumes the new cert creation set the NotBefore time to the current time when it was created.

Comment: Thanks @KeithHill!  Unfortunately, I am hoping to get the thumbnail at creation time.  If two CSRs are generated on the same day and then both requests completed on same day, it creates two certificates so I am trying to get the thumbnail for the most recently created certificate for that CN.  After this command, another will run to export the certificate.  Perhaps I should just delete existing certificates with the same CN created on the same day before completing the new request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `X509Certificate2` object from the file and grab the thumbprint from there.

```
$CertPath = "C:\my_csr_response.crt"
$Cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile($CertPath)
$Thumbprint = $Cert.GetCertHashString()
```

Find it in the cert store with:

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $Thumbprint}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias!  That will accomplish what I need!